# Is Keras LSTM the right choice?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, lstm

My Keras LSTM NN improves to a `val_loss` of around 0.005 when training with 75% of my 4000-s long time series. I've ran the GridSearchCV to tune the hyperparameters but when I try to predict the remaining 25% of the series I get unsatisfactory results. The predictions lose quality in its very first points.

[image: ![comparison between actual and predicted data]

The data is MinMax-scaled and I haven't bothered re-scaling yet since it wouldn't matter for now.

**Does it mean the LSTM is not adequate for my case? Is there anything else I could try?**

My time series comes from a dynamic FEM simulation with time step of 0.1 s, ie, two (or even more) consecutive points are very similar. To avoid redundant data I filtered the series to work with steps of 1 s.

I've also tried to use `tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator` but it starts training the NN for a few moments and then complains about the dimensions of the input (I'm trying to solve the issue on StackOverflow, but any help would be greatly appreciated). Regardless, I really don't see why this function would be important since my series is already in a `y=f(x)` kind of structure.